# Hiding a div using CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to force this div to be hidden with css:

```
<div class="db-logo">
```

When I inspect an element I can hide it like this:

```
<div class="db-logo" style="display:none;">
```

but how do I hide it with just css?
iv tried

```
<style>
.db-logo {
  display:none !important;
}

/*and*/

div .db-logo {
  display:none !important;
}
</style>
```

Neither worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your first attempt should work, your second is trying to find something with that class INSIDE a div. We'd need to see the CSS in action to tell you what is preventing the style from working (probably an inline style, or another `!important` somewhere else in the stylesheet)

Comment: ughhh neither are working

Comment: the only time they change is when i inspect element and do the changes

Comment: Post a [mcve] in your question please

Comment: @lonut dont know what you mean?

Comment: check in the dev tools if your style is overriden by another `!important` statement

Comment: @DavidBrierton Can you post your actual code? The code as you posted it has no issues and the first css selector should work. If they don't then you have something else interfering with that. Posting the rest of your CSS or HTML Markup that surrounds the elements in question should help identifying what the problem is.

Comment: Here is a useful video on how to debug css.. https://youtu.be/Z3HGJsNLQ1E?t=6m29s

Comment: i think the issue is that the css is being rendered after the page loads (css) i cannot control. So i was trying to put something on my page that overwrites theres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to impact (hide in this case) an element with CSS (via JS/jQuery not included):

**Example 1:** Impacting through external CSS class:

```
.db-logo {
    display: none !important;
}
```

```css
.db-logo {
    display: none !important;
    background: lightgray;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="db-logo"></div>
```

**Example 2:** Impacting through style on HTML element:

```
<div class="db-logo" style="display: none;"></div>
```

```css
.db-logo {
    /* display: none !important; */
    background: lightgray;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="db-logo" style="display: none;"></div>
```

**Example 3:** Impacting through `<style></style>` on HTML `head`:

```
<head>
  <style>
    .db-logo {
        display: none !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

```html
<style>
.db-logo {
    display: none !important;
    background: lightgray;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
</style>
<div class="db-logo"></div>
```